# Which is best way about delete row and insert row in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, model, laravel-5.1

As title, I have a table like student and another table is class.
User can edit about student having some class.
There is one to many relationship.
When user edit student's class, I always must to delete this student's class.
And insert the new class after that.

```
\App\class:where('student_id',$student->id)->delete();
foreach($request->input('class') as $class){
  $new = new \App\class;
  $new->student_id = $student->id;
  $new->class_id = $class;
  $new->save();
}
```

Is there have any solution about this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*For the moment I'll assume you have your relationships setup properly.*

You'll want to take a look at `sync`.

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

```
$student->classes()->sync($request->input('class'))
```

The `sync` method want's the ID's of the classes as argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This cause is about ManyToMany. I have another case for OneToMany. It's there have any other function for OneToMany?

Comment: @DavidLin Unfortunately there is no other way for an OneToMany relationship

Comment: @DavidLin Can you explain the relationship between the Class and Student? Can a student be in multiple classes? Does a class have multiple students?

Comment: And can you add your form to edit the student's classes to your post?